# Getting SSIS Error : [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, etl

I am trying to extract data from SageIntacct using CData and loading it into SQL. Currently I am just trying to dump the data into SQL. But I am getting following error:

[CData SageIntacct Source] Error: Column Modulekey has a maxmim length of 6. The value returned has a length of 11. As a result, some data will be truncated.

[CData SageIntacct Source] Error: Get data error: Column Modulekey has a maxmim length of 6. The value returned has a length of 11. As a result, some data will be truncated.

[CData SageIntacct Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQfTe.png)] Error: System.Exception: Get data error: Column Modulekey has a maxmim length of 6. The value returned has a length of 11. As a result, some data will be truncated.
at cta210K.kPx.PrimeOutput(Int32 , Int32[] , PipelineBuffer[] )
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPrimeOutput(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Int32 outputs, Int32[] outputIDs, IDTSBuffer100[] buffers, IntPtr ppBufferWirePacket)

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on CData SageIntacct Source returned error code 0x80131500.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I tried removing the problem column from the output table, changing all the columns in my source editor to Redirect Row and my Error output in destination to Redirect Row. Also I have tried Updating my Run64BitRuntime to True and False nothing works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtX2A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQfTe.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv4Bq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4QGP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The information in the image shows that the length of the Modulekey field in the destination table is determined by the value 6. while in the source table the field length is 11

Comment: The source and destination both have the value of 6

Comment: To test, change the field length to 12 in the destination table